# How to convert php md5(sha1(time())) in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, md5, hashlib

am new in python..

usually I do this in PHP `md5(sha1(time()))` and it convert something like: 017df9435b048f86ac28a274543ac46df5e20e0ecff32123a58287

Now how to do it in python3?

I've tried importing hashlib print(hashlib.md5(int(round(time.time() * 1)))) but not good results.

Can somebody help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does `print(hashlib.md5(int(time.time())))` work? The problem is that PHP's [`time()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) returns an integer of whole seconds since the epoch, while Python's [`time.time()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time) returns a float. `time.time()` also doesn't include leap seconds, while it's not clear if PHP's `time()` does or not.

Comment: Note that you are calculating the MD5 hash _of the SHA1 hash_ of the timestamp in PHP, but your Python code directly calculates the MD5 hash of the timestamp.

Comment: @MattDMo Not working buddy.

Comment: @luuk correct, that's what am looking for buddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not return same value as

```
md5(sha1(time()))
```

for same time because php functions md5 and sha1 return somebecausely different things than python3 functions hashlib.sha1 hashlib.md5, but following code might be what you want:

```
import hashlib,time
print(hashlib.md5(hashlib.sha1(str(int(round(time.time()))).encode()).hexdigest().encode()).hexdigest())
```

Comment: I had a stroke reading this answer.